# batchStore does not load generated keys

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I have a record like below (the first parameter is an `id serial PRIMARY KEY` in a postgresql DB).

```
SymbologyRecord symbology = new SymbologyRecord(null, "a", "b");
symbology.changed(SYMBOLOGY.ID, false);
```

When I insert the record with:

```
create.attach(symbology);
symbology.store();
assertNotNull(symbology.getId()); //passes
```

My test passes (the id gets uploaded from the DB after the insertion).

But if I use a `batchStore` the id remains null:

```
create.batchStore(symbology);
assertNotNull(symbology.getId()); //fails, id is null
```

Is that by design or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not by design. Ideally, the behaviour of [`batchStore()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batchStore-org.jooq.UpdatableRecord...-) should match that of [`UpdatableRecord.store()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/UpdatableRecord.html#store--) in every aspect, including fetching of IDs, which it currently doesn't. This is a known issue [#3327](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3327) per jOOQ 3.4